# convert data varchar (fraction) to decimal

Tags: vb.net

i have database with varchar type. in table `nilai` the are ("1/7" , "1/9" and etc). how to convert that data and calculate it

this is my code

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand("select colIndex, rowIndex , AVG(nilai)   from `tb_kuisionerahp` group by `colIndex`,`rowIndex`", Connector)
    rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While rs.Read
            dg1.Item(rs("colIndex"), rs("rowIndex")).Value = Val(rs("AVG(nilai)"))

        End While
        rs.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System

Public Class Program
Private Shared Function FractionToDouble(ByVal fraction As String) As Double
    Dim split As String() = fraction.Split(New Char() {" "c, "/"c})

    If split.Length = 2 Then
        Dim a, b As Integer

        If Integer.TryParse(split(0), a) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(split(1), b) Then

            If split.Length = 2 Then
                Return CDbl(a) / b
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Throw New FormatException("Not a valid fraction.")
End Function

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim fraction = "1/7"
    Console.WriteLine("Franction as double " & FractionToDouble(fraction))
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Microsoft Script Control.  To use this control, go to Project->Add Reference.  In the dialog that opens select the COM tab, scroll down to the Microsoft Script Control 1.0, select the control and click the Select button.  Click OK to accept the reference and close the dialog.  Then use strfraction2decimal function to get what you want , you can create new form application and paste theese codes there and see :

```
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox(strfraction2decimal("(1/3)"))
End Sub
Function strfraction2decimal(fraction As String) As Decimal
    Dim str_command As New StringBuilder
    str_command.AppendLine("function exec(param)")
    str_command.AppendLine("exec=(" & fraction & ")")
    str_command.AppendLine("End function")
    Dim sc As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
    sc.Language = "VBScript"
    sc.AddCode(str_command.ToString)
    Dim result = sc.Run("exec", "")
    Return result
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim div$ = Regex.Replace(
    "1/2",
    "(\d+)/(\d+)",
    Function(m) Decimal.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value / Decimal.Parse(m.Groups(2).Value)))
```